# What is wrong with the following merge sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, go, mergesort

As the question states, I'm having trouble finding where is the issue within the following algorithm. It is the aux function for mergesort, i.e. the one used for combining sorted arrays.

```
func Merge(toSort *[]int, p, q, r int) {
    arr := *toSort
    L := arr[p:q]
    R := arr[q:r+1]
    fmt.Println(L)
    fmt.Println(R)
    i := 0
    j := 0

    for index := p; index <= r; index++ {
        if i >= len(L) {
            arr[index] = R[j]
            j += 1
            continue
        } else if j >= len(R) {
            arr[index] = L[i]
            i += 1
            continue
        }

        if L[i] > R[j] {
            fmt.Println("right smaller")
            arr[index] = R[j]
            j += 1
            continue
        }
        if L[i] <= R[j] {
            fmt.Println("left smaller")
            arr[index] = L[i]
            i += 1
            continue
        }

    }

}
```

For `arr := []int{1,7,14,15,44,65,79,2,3,6,55,70}` it gives as output `[1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 6 55 70]`.

[Golang Play link](http://play.golang.org/p/OlrDxdFpIs)

The JavaScript equivalent for this function works as expected, but I don't know why it isn't working in `Go`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang slices are passed by reference. So you don't need to pass a pointer into the function in the first place, but you *do* need to take explicit copies of `L` and `R` or else merge into a different slice entirely. You are currently writing into the same underlying memory from which you are getting your values.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that I'm doing something wrong when using the language, because the js vesion was working just fine. Although, as I know, in js the array it's passed by reference too. But I think that array.splice function makes copies of the underlying array.

Answer (score 1):

Code like `L := arr[p:q]` does **not** create a copy. I suppose you are overwriting your L and R  parts  during the assignments to `arr`. Have a look at http://blog.golang.org/slices to understand how slices work. (E.g. you'll basically never write stuff like `toSort *[]int` as `[]int` is almost kinda pointer)

This seems to work: http://play.golang.org/p/vPo2ZKXtI9

Comment: I had 2 answers to accept, and it was hard but I choosed to accept Evan's because it was 1 minute faster. Ok, you corrected my program on playground too, but he has alot smaller rep points. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the indexes: slices are already views into an array. Here's a complete example using purely slice manipulation:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Merge takes two sorted, increasing slices of ints and
// returns a slice combining them into a single sorted, increasing
// slice.
func Merge(a, b []int) []int {
    res := make([]int, 0, len(a)+len(b))
    for len(a) > 0 || len(b) > 0 {
        if len(b) == 0 || len(a) > 0 && a[0] <= b[0] {
            res = append(res, a[0])
            a = a[1:]
        } else {
            res = append(res, b[0])
            b = b[1:]
        }
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 9}
    fmt.Println(Merge(a[:4], a[4:]))
}
```